# How to add rdf:datatype with EasyRdf

Tags: php, xml, rdf, easyrdf

I am using http://www.easyrdf.org/ PHP library to create an RDF document. I don't know how to add to the RDF document the `rdf:datatype`.

So what I am trying to achieve is

```
<rdf:Description rdf:datatype="&xsd:integer">58</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: Maybe with http://www.easyrdf.org/docs/api/EasyRdf_Literal.html

Comment: I'm creating something based on the code available here https://github.com/njh/easyrdf/blob/d1512729e452ff68ed1c623463906c2fb5d0c2ce/test/EasyRdf/Serialiser/RdfXmlTest.php#L267

Comment: In general, `<rdf:Description rdf:about="x"><hasValue rdf:datatype="&xsd;integer">58</hasValue></rdf:Description>` denotes the triple `x hasValue "58"^^xsd:integer`.  It sounds like you're asking how to add literals as the objects of triples, so @RobertRozas's suggestion to look at the Literal API is good.  Using `rdf:Description` as a property isn't a great idea though;  it's used in the RDF/XML serialization of RDF to denote a resource.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This produces the desired effect

```
// Add xsd:integer to the resource
$rdf_resource->add(
    'rdf:Description',
    EasyRdf_Literal::create(58, null, 'xsd:integer')
);
```

Comment: What you're doing in that is adding `"58"^^xsd:integer` as the value of the `rdf:Description` property.  You've got the integer part right, but `rdf:Description` shouldn't be used as a property like that;  it's used in the RDF/XML serialization of an RDF document as an element denoting an RDF resource.

Comment: Also, if this worked for you, don't forget to accept your answer (there might be a time limit, though).

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I agree with you that rdf:Description should not be used like that. I actually use a custom namespace to store that value. I did not add it in the code sample because it is not part of the standard namespaces.